# Python logging.config.fileConfig and platform-independent config files

Tags: python, logging

I am working with a python application that makes use of the logging.config.fileConfig() function to load a logging configuration.  The problem is that some of the logging handlers are FileHandlers which require the file path as one of the arguments and my application needs to run on Linux and Windows.

Is there a way to specify the file path in a platform-independent way.  I know you would normally use os.path.join("path", "to", "file.log") but that doesn't seem to work in this scenario.

For example, the logging config file has a section like this:

```
 [handler_messageHandler]
 class=handlers.RotatingFileHandler
 level=DEBUG
 formatter=complex
 args=('.\\log\\message.log', 'a', 5000000,4)
```

which is find on windows but is incorrect on linux.  I know i could simply provide two config files but with each file at well over 100 lines long this seems like a hacky copy-and-paste solution. Ideally I'd like to be able to do something like this in the config file:

```
 [handler_messageHandler]
 class=handlers.RotatingFileHandler
 level=DEBUG
 formatter=complex
 args=(os.path.join('.', log', 'message.log'), 'a', 5000000,4)
```

Comment: Windows secretly accepts forward slashes, so the quick hack approach is to spell it `./log/message.log` on both systems.